# How do I configure the automatic suspend setting?

Tags: suspend

I just bought acer netbook which came with Ubuntu One program, whenever I'm watching videos on youtube system gives me warning that netbook will automatically suspend because of inactivity and it does if I don't press cancel. please tell me why does it happen and what can I do to stop it. thank you

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of that dialog/warning? I've never seen anything like that before..

Comment: sure, just give me couple of minutes

Comment: OMG! I'm so stupid! I found the solution myself! all I had to do was that I had to change automatic suspend settings. Thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 and this steps would help you with your issue. If you are running a different version of Ubuntu the steps might change.

On your "System Settings", click on "Brightness & Lock". On "Turn screen off when inactive for:" from the pull-down menu select "Never".