# ubuntu 17.10 automatic suspend while playing videos

Tags: suspend

[image]while watching video it is saying will automatically suspend due to inactivity.I have updated my system to 17.10.It was not happening previously.
I did check this 
[How do I configure the automatic suspend setting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409920/how-do-i-configure-the-automatic-suspend-setting)
Is there is other solution?
Thanks :)

Edit :I have search all the question of this type and even I did mention about similar question,the Question you are mentioning was not there,Please see the date of Question.

Comment: What video player software are you using?

Comment: i am playing it on google chrome.